# PHP Preg_match_all regexp pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I need your help for a pattern i can't do myself.

I got this file :

```
    description1="SIOUH : Authentification Cerbere - Acces"
    description2="Acces formulaire authentification SIOUH"
    addheader="Pragma: no-cache "
    method="get"
    url="${AUTH_URL}/login/LoginDispatchAction.do?appId=${APP_ID}&backURL=${APP_URL_ENC}"
    errormessage="Phase 1 : Impossible atteindre le formulaire authentification CERBERE pour SIOUH"
    serveur="yes"
    verifypositive="loginConnectAppliForm"
    logrequest="yes" logresponse="no" />
```

I have this preg_match_all which works perfectly :

```
preg_match_all  ( '#(.*?)="(.*?)"#s', $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ); //Chaque option
```

My problem is i can have simple quotes instead of double, how can i change my pattern to handle it?
Example, i need to catch this line like all others:

```
parseresponse='name="conversationId" value="|"'
```

Thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backreference to require the closing quote to match the opening one:

```
'#(.*?)=([\'"])(.*?)\2#'
```

Comment: Perfect ! Didn't know it was possible to do this. I was going on '#(.*?)=(?:(?:\'(.*?)\')|(?:"(.*?)"))#' but yours is better. Thank !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use regex liek this

```
^(.*?)=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]$
```

Comment: As i can have [logrequest = "yes" logresponse = "yes"] on 1 line, i can't use ^ and $ i nmy regexp. If i use [\'"] instead of my ", i got this :   Array
        (
            [0] => parseresponse='name="
            [1] => parseresponse
            [2] => name=
        )
Because i got a double quote in my simple quote (parsereponse is a pattern) which is catched and shouldn't be.

Comment: Then try to use greedy capture - remove ? from second group of round brackets

Comment: With '#(\w*?)=["\'](.*)["\']#' i got a trouble with the [logrequest = "yes" logresponse = "yes"] which is on the same line